# Display Image light color as ImageView Preloader

Tags: android, imageview, preloader

Right now iam using **picasso** as an image loading library, It download and show the image with no problem.

I saw some of the apps using image main color as its **preloader** background is it possible? i mean is there any library i saw **android support v7 palette** but no idea how to use with **picasso** and i also search lot but no success.

Please tell me if there is any library.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can set placeholder like,

```
Picasso.with(context)
   .load(thumbnail_url) 
   .into(imageView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(image_url) // image url 
                    .placeholder(imageView.getDrawable())
                    .into(imageView);
        }
        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });
```

you can also refer,
[picasso-placeholders](https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-placeholders-errors-and-fading).